# $digest(), pushState, History errors

Tags: angularjs

We have an AngularJS application (v1.2.0-rc.3).

The application contains a link to a website outside of our Angular application:

```
$window.location.href = "http://www.someotherwebsite.com";
```

On Chrome mobile, we see that when the user visits this link and uses the back button on the mobile to come back into the Angular application, we get errors:

```
$rootScope.infdig...
$digest() iterations reached...
Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations...
$locationWatch...
ngModelWatch...
Property 'pushState' of object [object History] is not a function...
```

What is wrong? and do we resolve this?

EDIT:

Upgrading AngularJS to v1.2.15 resolves the problem.

Comment: I upgraded the AngularJS version to v1.2.15, and now the errors disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading AngularJS to v1.2.15 resolves the problem.